# How to write dictionary into CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Keep getting error when trying to copy selected rows of a original csv file into a new csv file. I only wanted to copy those rows which the column 2 contain "B" into a new csv file and similarly for those in "M". Another challenge I facing is because the original CSV file contains float.

Managed to rename my header and write in the new csv file because the original headers are too wordy so thought of re-labelling them with numbers for easy calling.

**Original csv file**
[image]

**new csv file**
[image]

```
import csv

with open("breast_cancer_v1.csv", newline='') as original, open("benign.csv", "w", newline='') as benign:

    fieldnames = ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(benign, fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()   

    print ("\nColumn \ Description title", "\n1:  ID", "\n2:  Diagnosis", "\n3:  a) radius (mean of distances from center to points on the perimeter)", "\n4:  b) texture (standard deviation of gray-scale values)", "\n5:  c) perimeter", "\n6:  d) area", "\n7:  e) smoothness (local variation in radius lengths)", "\n8:  f) compactness (perimeter^2 / area - 1.0)", "\n9:  g) concavity (severity of concave portions of the contour)", "\n10: h) concave points (number of concave portions of the contour)", "\n11: i) symmetry", "\n12: j) fractal dimension (coastline approximation - 1)")

    csv_file = csv.DictReader(original, fieldnames)

    next(csv_file) 

    col_1 = 3
    col_2 = 4
    B_row_count = 0
    M_row_count = 0
    B_sum = 0
    M_sum = 0

    for row in csv_file:

        if (row['2'] == "B"):

            B_sum += float(row[str(col_1)])
            B_row_count += 1 
            writer.writerow(row)

        elif (row['2'] == "M"):

            M_sum += float(row[str(col_1)])
            M_row_count += 1 

print ("\nNo. of patients (rows) under benign(B) group is: " + str(B_row_count))        
print ("No. of patients (rows) under malignant(M) group is: " + str(M_row_count))   
print ("\nTotal No. of patients (rows) is: " + str(B_row_count + M_row_count))
```

**Error msg is:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\final
>   coursework\Final coursework.py", line 69, in 
>       B_sum += float(row[str(col_1)])   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\csv.py",
>   line 153, in writerow
>       return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\csv.py",
>   line 149, in _dict_to_list
>       + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields])) builtins.ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None

Comment: What is the error you get when you run this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\final coursework\Final coursework.py", line 66, in <module>
    M_row_count += 1
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
builtins.ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None

i just want to copy the while line, what fieldnames to key in?

Comment: sorry. just start to use stack overflow, wasn't familiar here. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: It's hard to tell looking at the images, but I think that the original csv goes to column L, but your new names only go to K. If you add '12' to your fieldnames do you still get the error?

Comment: Oh my!!!, you spotted the mistake!!! yes, i missed out 1 column header. Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: @Newbiecoder have you solved it?

Comment: Hi, yup it's solved. short of 1 column header.